# Display last date grouped by warehouse and product

Tags: mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called `daily_stock` with the following fields:

```
+-----------+----------+------------+----------+
| warehouse | product  | date       | stock    |
+-----------+----------+------------+----------+
| 01        | A        | 2016/04/01 | 100      |
| 01        | A        | 2016/04/05 | 80       |
| 01        | A        | 2016/04/18 | 35       |
| 02        | A        | 2016/04/02 | 1        |
| 02        | A        | 2016/04/06 | 10       |
| 02        | A        | 2016/04/16 | 18       |
| 01        | B        | 2016/04/03 | 25       |
| 01        | B        | 2016/04/11 | 66       |
| 01        | B        | 2016/04/29 | 45       |
| 02        | B        | 2016/04/05 | 19       |
| 02        | B        | 2016/04/19 | 1        |
+-----------+----------+------------+----------+
```

Now I need to display products last date with stock in all warehouses.

The result I am trying to get is:

```
+----------+----------+------------+----------+
| 01       | A        | 2016/04/18 | 35       |
| 02       | A        | 2016/04/16 | 18       |
| 01       | B        | 2016/04/29 | 45       |
| 02       | B        | 2016/04/19 | 1        |
+----------+----------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Please add what RDBMS you are using. That will help get you an answer.

Comment: I am using MariaDB 10.0 with HeidiSQL if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you? I am testing in MySQL.

```
SELECT LatestStock.*
FROM daily_stock as LatestStock
JOIN (  
    SELECT warehouse, product, MAX([date]) as MAXdate
    FROM daily_stock 
    GROUP BY warehouse, product
    ) as LatestDate on LatestStock.warehouse = LatestDate.warehouse AND LatestStock.product = LatestDate.product AND LatestStock.date = LatestDate.MAXdate
ORDER BY LatestStock.product, LatestStock.warehouse
```

Comment: I get 0 results with this query :( Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Do you get results if you just run the inner query to find the latest date for warehouse and product?

Comment: Yes, i get results if i only run the inner query. I think i can work with that! Thank you!

Comment: How about if i have more months in the date field? How would i go and show stock on last day in month for all the months in data table?

Comment: @HEki: That looks like a different question, even if similar.

Comment: @HEki that is a different question, but try looking here, http://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/functions/last_day.php